# View html, htm, etc as plain text

Tags: html, plaintext

I was wondering if there is a way to link to a page like `domain.com/index.htm` and view it as plain text / code instead of the browser actually rendering the page.

Even better yet, if this is possible with php scripts, that would be incredible. (This would not be a link to an external page, but rather one on my own ftp site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a php handler to do it, eg `getHtml.php?file=index.html`, then use `file_get_contents` and `htmlspecialchars` to output it.

Comment: This looks promising. Would this be possible with php scripts as well?

Comment: @Richard, yes it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "view page source" in a browser?

You can bring down all the text using Java by making a URL connection and reading the stream.  I don't know what PHP's capabilities to do so might be.

Comment: More like when you go to example.com/main.css and it will literally show the page in plain text. Or if its a .js file, it does the same. Hoping to pull this off with htm / html extensions

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome and Firefox, you can enter

```
view-source:http://www.server.com/page.html
```

in the address bar and the browser will open the page's source without rendering it.

As for PHP, you cannot see the source of the script unless the server gives it to you in a separate request (see Paul Creasy's answer).

Answer (score 0):

PHP installer registers `phps` extension in apache mime types list (with `application/x-httpd-php-source` mime type). It stands for PHP source and PHP does highlighting itself: http://yhub.ru/test.phps

Unfortunately, as you can see, it doesn't support HTML highlighting.